# Document.title is not working on clearing cache

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I am creating a window using the following code

```
var myWindow=window.open(MyUrl,"","resizable=yes,menubar=no,status=yes,scrollbars=no", fullscreen = "1");
```

and I am changing the window title dynamically using

```
myWindow.document.title = "My Title";
```

it is not working for the first time after clearing the IE(Internet Explorer) cache. but it is working for the next time in the same browser i.e., if we dont clear the cache it is working what could be the reason for this and does anybody know how to resolve this.

More Info: when I debug I am getting an error "call was rejected by callee" what does it mean. this is happening only for the first time, whenever I clear my IE cache and for rest of the times its working fine

Please guide me

thanks in advance..!

Comment: Are you waiting for the document to load before changing the title?

Comment: yes, I am waiting I have an if(myWindow.document){.....} condition

Comment: and when I debug I am getting an error "call was rejected by callee" what does it mean. this is happening only for the first time, whenever I clear my IE cache and for rest of the times its working fine

Comment: this works fine in chrome, checkout - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eZENRX

Comment: working fine in chrome I have issue in IE-11

Comment: @vinodkumar: An `if` doesn't wait. Do you have some kind of onload callback or timeout?